# ggplot - geom_point with shape and colour dictated by variable, where colour comes from a custom palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's the data frame I want to plot:

```
   age composite_col  frequency
1   18          var1 0.65531200
2   19          var1 0.48697446
3   20          var1 0.21423509
4   21          var1 0.38887071
5   22          var1 0.27072698
6   23          var1 0.76371308
7   18          var2 0.05554554
8   19          var2 0.65048383
9   20          var2 0.98546390
10  21          var2 0.04171436
11  22          var2 0.13346492
12  23          var2 0.21246432
```

Here's the code for generating the dataframe:

```
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1911)
df_se = data.frame(age = c(18,19,20,21,22,23), var1 = runif(6,0,1), var2 = runif(6,0,1) )

df_se = gather(df_se, "composite_col","frequency",c(var1,var2))
df_se
```

---

I want to produce a single graph that consists of:

1. A line graph where the colours dictated by the variable `composite_col`
2. Overlayed geom_points with the both the colours and shapes dictated by the variable `composite_col`
3. A black outline around the shapes

---

my attempt at a solution:

```
p = ggplot(data = df_se)

p = p + geom_line( aes(x=age, y=frequency, colour=composite_col) )

p = p + geom_point(aes(x = age, y= frequency, shape = composite_col, fill = composite_col, colour = "black"), pch = 21, size = 2.5) 

p = p + scale_colour_manual(values=c("#DF4A2A", "#3D9813"))

p
```

produces the following error:

```
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.
```

When I add more colours to my palette it produces a graph but the colours are completely wrong and the scale is completely wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the outline of each point should always be black, you need to remove the `colour = "black"` line outside of the `aes()` call.

```
ggplot(data = df_se, aes(x=age, y=frequency)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour=composite_col)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=composite_col, fill=composite_col), colour="black", pch=21, size=2.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("#DF4A2A", "#3D9813"))
```

And if you want the color of the point to match the color of the line, you can add a scale for the fill:

```
ggplot(data = df_se, aes(x=age, y=frequency)) +
    geom_line( aes(colour=composite_col) ) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = composite_col, fill = composite_col), colour = "black", pch = 21, size = 2.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("#DF4A2A", "#3D9813")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#DF4A2A", "#3D9813"))
```

Edit:

And to specify the shape with `scale_shape_manual`, you will need to remove the `pch` parameter from your `geom_point`:

```
ggplot(data = df_se, aes(x=age, y=frequency)) +
    geom_line( aes(colour=composite_col) ) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = composite_col, fill = composite_col), colour = "black", size = 2.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("#DF4A2A", "#3D9813")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#DF4A2A", "#3D9813")) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(3, 16))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the only problem with this solution is that the shapes of the points don't change - it's always a circle

Comment: I've tried with scale_shape_manual(values = c(22,23)) but this doesn't work

Comment: The `pch` parameter was overriding your scale. See my edit.